# Как получить значение атрибута тега при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть верстка вида и часть JS-кода, обрабатывающие клик.

```js
   $('important').click(function {
      var ID = Number($(this).attr('unical-id'));
   var parentCheck = $('id-'+ID).find('wonder');
   var isOne = (Number(parentCheck.attr('item'))==1)?0:1;
      if (isOne == 1){
             ...
             }
             else ...
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id-43">
  <div class="styling">
    <div class="wonder" item=1>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="id-44">
  <div class="styling">
    <div class="wonder" item=1>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="id-45">
  <div class="styling">
    <div class="wonder" item=1>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="simple">
    <div class="something important" unical-id=44>
      <p class="typical">Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос в том, как получить корректную переменную isOne из значения атрибута при помощи jQuery. Селектор вроде правильно задаю, но сравнения не происходит. jQuery знаю плохо, потому вероятно есть решение, как считать данные произвольного атрибута из вложенного элемента в определенном месте верстки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выборка по классу - нужна точка перед названием класса:

```
$('.important')...

...find('.wonder');
```

`#` - перед идентификатором

```
$('#id-'+ID)...
```

скобки после `function()`.

```
$('.important').click(function() {
  var ID = Number($(this).attr('unical-id'));
  var parentCheck = $('#id-' + ID).find('.wonder');
  var isOne = (Number(parentCheck.attr('item')) == 1)? 0 : 1;
  if (isOne == 1){
    console.log("found");//...
  } else {
    console.log("not found");//...
  }
});
```

Comment: Я в общем виде написал, это отрывок из большого куска кода. Там много логики, постарался передать как можно короче суть вопроса. 
И да, вы мне помогли, проблема как раз вы отсутствующих точках перед названием класса. Дырявая голова смотрела в консоли на селектор без точек, но в упор не понимала, что может быть не так :(
Спасибо. Будет вперёд наука как оформлять кусок на стаке грамотно :)